# Using osmnx with pyinstall

Tags: pyinstaller, osmnx, fiona

I am trying to convert an `osmnx` based Python program into a windows executable. This is so that I can run the `.exe` on machines that don't have a Python installation. Here's a simple program called `myprogram.py` that uses `osmnx` to get hold of a street network and then print it.

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Cardiff, UK', network_type='drive')
ox.plot_graph(G)
```

This simple code runs correctly. The next step is to generate a single executable file. Using pyinstaller this is achieved by going to the command prompt and typing

```
pyinstaller --onefile myprogram.py
```

This generates the required executable. However, if I try to run this, I get the following errors.

```
Matplotlib is building the font cache; this may take a moment.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myprogram.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "osmnx\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "osmnx\_api.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "osmnx\bearing.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "osmnx\projection.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "geopandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "geopandas\io\file.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "fiona\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading' (most likely due to a circular import)
[11400] Failed to execute script 'myprogram' due to unhandled exception!
```

As shown, the problem seems to be with some circular references. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237076/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-fiona-has-no-attribute-loading
I had left a comment at that question. Can you install OSMnx using its documented installation instructions? https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ The OSMnx project doesn't formally support other installation methods, such as pyinstaller, so your results may vary.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yes, `osmnx` has been installed using the recommended linked instructions. But the error still occurs. Perhaps this is something that could be resolved in a future version? Thanks for the great library by the way!

Comment: This isn't a limitation of OSMnx itself: the package is pure python and trivial to install. However, some of its dependencies have C extensions and thus complicated installs. You'd have to discuss with the relevant package generating the error when using pyinstaller.

Comment: The circular import is a Fiona issue. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69411131/7321942